# ionic start projectName blank - error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

When I try to create an application with `ionic start firstapp blank`
I get to this error:

```
√ Creating directory .\firstapp - done!
[INFO] Fetching app base (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-
base/archive/master.tar.gz)
× Downloading - failed!
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com github.com:443
```

Anybody have an idea about what is wrong please?

Win 10
Ionic 3.6
npm 5.3
nodejs 6.11.1

Comment: which os/version are you using?

Comment: Win 10 and am using the latest version of ionic 3.6

Comment: try to flush your dns `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: I do this and here is the result ?

    [INFO] Fetching app base (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-
    base/archive/master.tar.gz)
   × Downloading - failed! 
   Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Comment: Can you check your date/time?

Comment: My datetime system is correct 2017/07/31 15:45